# Is it possible to return value from ribbon tool bar button to simple text field?

Tags: tridion2009, tridion

I added a button to return the value from popup page to the RTF field. But my current requirement is to add the value to the simple text field. Can anyone please suggest me a way how can I return the value to the simple text field?

Comment: Please show your code example for doing this with an RTF filed- That will help us understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Please also specify the version of SDL Tridion you are using. You have tagged this a Tridion 2009 - But the questions seems more related to 2011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can't do that in supported way because there are no API to get access to Field Builder control from the View.
If you'll decide to workaround this (accessing private properties, some other hacks), you can achieve this by using Field Builder control API. For example:

```
var field = fieldBuilder.getFocusField(); // returns currently focused field object
field.getValues();  // returns field values (might be more than 1 in case of multivalue fields
field.setValues([...]); // sets field values
```

But be careful, that by clicking on the Ribbon Toolbar Button focus will be moved out from the field to the Ribbon Toolbar Button. So `fieldBuilder.getFocusField()` will return `null`.
One of the possible solutions to listen for the `"focusmove"` event on Field Builder control to track focused fields.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For getting publication Id we will use the command
"$display.getView().getItem().getPublicationId()". 
similarly for the getFocusField(), which object need to be used?
Please explain more about getting the focus of the current field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my component creation page I have multivalued Embedded schema fields. To access the complete XML of the component I am using the command: "$display.getView().getItemFields()" . For a particular RTF field I am using the command: "target.editor.getHTML()" . But my requirement is to get the complete set of Embedded field values. Which command I need to use? Please help in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I already said, you should use filedBulider instance object to call "getFocusField" method on it. And there are no public API for getting access to that object. But you could use not supported and not documented way of accessing "private" object:

$display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder.getFocusField()